# VBA Unix to DOS text conversion code error

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I am currently working on a code that creates a text file to dump data from a Unix data file into a temp text file which I can access in vba for post processing of data. My macro works only when this file is in a DOS format so I am trying to convert the Line feeds from Unix to DOS. Right now I am getting an error when I try to write out the revised text to the temp file. My code is listed below

```
    Filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(".f06 files (*.f06),*.f06")
    Dim tempFilepath As String
    tempFilepath = Replace(Filepath, ".f06", "_temp.txt")

    Dim realfile As Integer
    realfile = FreeFile
    Dim tempfile As Integer
    tempfile = FreeFile
    Dim FileContent As String

    Open tempFilepath For Output As tempfile
    Close #1
    Open Filepath For Input As realfile

    Do While Not EOF(realfile)
         Line Input #realfile, FileContent
         FileContent = Replace(FileContent, Chr(10), vbCrLf)
         Print #tempfile, FileContent
    Loop
```

I am getting the error on the line:

Print

```
    #tempfile, FileContent
```

with a Run-time Error 54, Bad file mode.

Just wondering if anybody can see a glaring error to help me fix my code! I've been scouring the internet for the last two days trying to get this task done in different ways but haven't been able to manage it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freefile returns the same handle number until you actually open a file using that handle. Tested the code above and Realfile and Tempfile both turn out to be 1. This confuses the hell out of file handling APIs.

Ideal way to do this is to open the file immediately after calling FreeFile and then call it again when you need to open another file. Final code:

```
Filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(".f06 files (*.f06),*.f06")
Dim tempFilepath As String
tempFilepath = Replace(Filepath, ".f06", "_temp.txt")

Dim realfile As Integer
realfile = FreeFile()
Open Filepath For Input As realfile

Dim tempfile As Integer
tempfile = FreeFile()
Open tempFilepath For Output As tempfile

Dim FileContent As String

Do While Not EOF(realfile)
     Line Input #realfile, FileContent
     FileContent = Replace(FileContent, Chr(10), vbCrLf)
     Print #tempfile, FileContent
Loop

Close tempfile
Close realfile
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure that was something I would have been stuck on for a while. However, that has not solved the original error message I was receiving. Do you have any other ideas on possible problems?

Comment: Tried this standalone. Works perfectly at my end (Excel VBA 2016). Are you sure that you have copied the code verbatim. Please note that I have removed the Close #1 statement that was inappropriately placed. What's the size of files you are trying to convert?

Comment: Ahh that close statement was the other problem because I had a previous error in which it said the file was already open. Thank you so much, that works perfectly!